# Change the width of the off-canvas dialog

Tags: 8, layout-builder

Layout Builder uses the off-canvas dialog. It comes out from the right side of the screen at a max width of 300px. We'd like to make it wider. I can do this with a powerful CSS rule, but is there a better Drupal way? Is there a setting I can't find?

Comment: There is no config setting for this. You could alternatively probably change it via [hook_link_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_link_alter/8.6.x) but to me it makes less sense to set the width via PHP rather than CSS.

Comment: If the width doesn't depend from a value you get using the Drupal API, for example the state API or the configuration API, it's better to do that via CSS.

Comment: There's also a modal available for better UX: https://www.drupal.org/project/layout_builder_modal

Answer (score 0):

You Can modify the initial width of the offCanvasDialog by setting the 'data-dialog-options'.  We're doing that in the same_page_preview module with this implementation:

```
$form['toggle_preview_link'] = [
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#title' => t('Launch preview'),
  '#weight' => -1,
  '#url' => Url::fromRoute('same_page_preview.preview_pane', $route_parameters),
  '#attributes' => [
    'class' => ['use-ajax', 'button','button--primary', 'visually-hidden'],
    'data-dialog-type' => 'dialog',
    'data-dialog-renderer' => 'off_canvas',
    'data-dialog-options' => Json::encode([
      'width' => '50%',
      'classes' => [
        // @todo figure out how to override more than just this one.
        'ui-dialog' => 'same-page-preview-dialog',
      ],
    ]),
  ],
  '#attached' => [
    'library' => [
      'core/drupal.dialog.ajax',
    ],
  ],
];
```

This sets the initial width of the dialog to be 50% of the page.

Modifying the width of the dialog after it renders can be done manually by dragging with edge of the dialog.  I'm also looking into modifying the width programmatically but don't have that figured out right now. I'll come back here if I do figure it out.